# Multi prefix search with multi keys

Tags: elasticsearch

A user wants to search a person by name and enter therefore something like:

- "Pe Lu"
- "Peter L"
- "Lustig P"

All of these should match "Peter Lustig".

The data is indexed with default settings having firstname and lastname split.

I tried to use default prefix search using a bool "should" query having splitted the search term by whitespace.

```
bool
    should
         prefix
               firstName Pe
         prefix
               name Pe
         prefix
               firstName Lu
         prefix
               name Lu
```

But I do not get any results for this. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use [`ngram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer) tokenizer.

Comment: Could you please confirm fields `name` and `firstName` are not analized ? It's a prerequisite to use `prefix`.

Comment: Confirmed... the search itself is working if I only use name or firstName... but the combination does not work.

Comment: Could you please try in lower case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try following query:;

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
       "should": [
          {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "firstName": "Peter"
            }
          },
           {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "firstName": "Lu"
            }
          },
           {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "lastName": "Peter"
            }
          },
           {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "lastName": "Lu"
            }
          }
       ]
    }
  }
 }
```